# How to only allow number as input? - Python

Tags: python, input

I want to make a simple Python IP Tracker with IP Format only, but i'm confused cause i can't filter the input. 
This is my code:

```
while True:
    ip= raw_input("What Your Target IP : ")
    url = "http://blabla.com/json/"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url + ip)
    data = response.read()
    values = json.loads(data)

    print("------------------------------------")
    print "\r"
    print(" IP: " + values['query'])
    print(" City: " + values['city'])
    print(" Region: " + values['regionName'])
    print(" Country: " + values['country'])
    print(" Time Zone: " + values['timezone'])
    print "\r"

    break
```

Comment: Use the stdlib [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress) module.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You don't want to check for numbers, you want to check for valid IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression or IP address module to resolve your problem

```
import re
import os
import urllib2
import json
while True:
    ip = raw_input("What Your Target IP : ")
    if not re.match(("^\d{0,9}\.\d{0,9}\.\d{0,9}\.\d{0,9}$"), ip):
        print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
    else:
        print("You picked number "+ ip)
        url = "https://blablabla/"
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url + ip)
        data = response.read()
        values = json.loads(data)

print("------------------------------------")
print "\r"
print(" IP           :  " + values['ip'])
print(" City         :  " + values['city'])
print(" Region       :  " + values['region'])
print(" Country      :  " + values['country_name'])
print(" Continent    :  " + values['continent_name'])
print(" Time Zone    :  " + values['time_zone'])
print(" Currency     :  " + values['currency'])
print(" Calling Code :  " + "+" + values['calling_code'])
print(" Organisation :  " + values['organisation'])
print(" ASN          :  " + values['asn'])
print "\r"
```

Comment: I got an error here, but i don't know how to use code formatting in comment.

Comment: `print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
                                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: got an error in )

Comment: Check this [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/eb6g7) < it's my code after your answer

Comment: Your indentation does not match the answer suggested here

Comment: This is all code, [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/wxpgx) . Is there something I miss?

Comment: in the code a **print()** function will be in the from the if condition and else condition as my above code how the print () function followed the indention of if & else condition it should look like these :

Comment: Would you help me set the code and put it in ghostbin?

Comment: I did. And i have new error :( Check this [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/8swgg)

Comment: @Abay  thanx for accepting